# How to setup Spring Data JPA repositories without component scanning

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For performance reasons I'm switching from component scanning to explicitly declaring my beans. So basically I want to remove `@EnableJpaRepositories` as it scans for repositories.

My repositories are standard interfaces extending `JpaRepository`. How can I declare my repositories?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create individual repository instances by declaring a `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` manually:

```
@Configuration
class Config {

  @Bean
  public JpaRepositoryFactoryBean userRepository() {
    JpaRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setRepositoryInterface(UserRepository.class);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

This will cause Spring to call `getObject()` to obtain the repository proxy from the factory and potentially inject it into clients.

However, I'd argue that - if not configured blatantly wrong - the overhead of scanning for repositories is neglectable, esp. compared to the time initializing an `EntityManagerFactory` takes.

Comment: Component scanning can be a performance pain in some cloud runtimes (namely Google App Engine) where app instances need to "warm up" (basically full re-deploy) after some iddle time. Your solution might be more useful than you expect, thanks!

Comment: @Oliver Gierke This is all good but there is one small issue. Since my application is multitenant i can't create JpaRepositoryFactoryBean  like above. is there a way to create it lazily? also JpaRepositoryFactoryBean is attached with userRepository, how to create multiple factory beans for this?

Comment: Do you have to create a factory bean for each repository?

Comment: @oliver-drotbohm fastforward in 2022 if i do this in AutoConfiguration project my other repositories inside the client apps are null :/

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Oliver. However, in time API of Spring Data JPA apparently has changed and in the current version (2.2.3) the snippet should look more like below:

```
@Configuration
class Config {

  @Bean
  // assuming userId is String
  public JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<UserRepository, User, String> userRepository() {
    JpaRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean(UserRepository.class);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to configure a concrete repository bean you can directly use the factory to create it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class NotificationConfig {

    @Bean
    public NotificationRepository notificationRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory=new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
        return jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(NotificationRepository.class);
    }

}
```